# How to customise multiline table view header in Swift?

Tags: swift, tableview

How can I edit the multiline header style in swift? Can I let the "Next Week" to bold and the date to regular? Another question is how to add some padding at the bottom of header?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if section == 0{
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)
        header.textLabel?.text = "Next Week \n \(firstDay) - \(seventhDay)"
        header.textLabel?.frame = header.frame
        header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    }
}
```

Current code

[image: Current code layout]

App design
[image: App design layout]

Comment: Take a look at `NSAttributedString` for modifying the style of just a part of a string.

Comment: Another option is to create custom header view.

Comment: Pretty simple. What part do you not know how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make one part of the string bold and keep the other part in regular, you can use `NS(Mutable)AttributedString`. This allows you to set all different kinds of stylings just for particular parts of the string:

```
let header = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
var mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Next Week \n \(firstDay) - \(seventhDay)", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:18.0)!])
mutableString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"Helvetica-Bold", size:18.0)!], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 9)) //lenght 9 because "Next Week" is 9 characters
header.textLabel?.attributedText = mutableString
```

Then to add a padding simply make the textLabel's height smaller then the header's height but make them start at the same height.

```
header.textLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: header.frame.width, height: header.frame.height-20) //minX and minY because the screen renders from top left
header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
```

Comment: About the padding. any other method? The current code seem not working

Comment: why frame.height - 20?

Comment: I have another question. when I scroll down and then scroll back to top. The header text alignment went to the left. why?

Comment: I made a mistake, I forget that frames are relative to each other so the x and y of the textlabel should just be 0, I updated my answer

Comment: I do minus 20 to add a 20 padding by making the textlabel 20 shorter than the header.